# Calculus problem with negative infinity

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} x(\sqrt{x²+1}-x)$$

Can someone simplify this and explain the steps. I'm having problems getting rid of sqrt.

Comment: Both $x$ and  $\sqrt{x^2+1}-x$ are infinitely large as $x$ tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: This might help: $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \sqrt{x^2+1}=|x|=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} -x=\infty$

Answer (score 5):

No need to get rid of the square root.  As $x\to -\infty$, both $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and $-x$ go to $+\infty$, and thus the product goes to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

For $x \gt 0$:  $x \lt \sqrt{x^2+1} \lt  x+\tfrac{1}{2x}$ as you can check by squaring both sides, with the right-hand expression being very close for large $x$.

So for $x \lt 0$:  $-x \lt \sqrt{x^2+1} \lt  -x-\tfrac{1}{2x}$

So for $x \lt 0$: $-2x^2  \gt  x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x) \gt -2x^2 - \frac12$

and so the limit as $x \to -\infty$ is $-\infty$, and for large negative $x$, we have $-2x^2 - \frac12$ as an excellent lower bound

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty}\sqrt{x^2+1}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}\sqrt{x^2(1+1/x^2)}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}|x|\sqrt{1+1/x^2}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}|x|\sqrt{1}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}|x|$

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)=\lim_{x \to -\infty}x(\sqrt{x^2(1+1/x^2)}-x)=\ \lim_{x \to -\infty}x(|x|-x)=\lim_{x \to -\infty}x((-x)-x)=\lim_{x \to -\infty}-2x^2=-\infty$$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty}|x|=\lim_{x \to -\infty}(-x)$ because by definition of $|x|$ we know that $|x|=-x$ when $x<0$ and in this case because $x$ is approaching $-\infty$ we know $x<0$.

as a general rule, if you have an algebraic expression and $x \to \infty$ only the highest degree term will matter, because you can factor the highest degree term and you'll have two factors, one is the highest degree term and the other goes to $1$ Like the following case:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=\lim_{x \to \infty}a_nx^n(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_nx}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{a_nx^{n-1}}+\frac{a_0}{a_nx^n})=\lim_{x \to \infty}a_nx^n.\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_nx}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{a_nx^{n-1}}+\frac{a_0}{a_nx^n})=\lim_{x \to \infty}a_nx^n.1=\lim_{x \to \infty}a_nx^n$

Answer (score -1):

At infinity sqrt( x^2+1) tends to x. So we have for the limitation process something like Lim x (x - x) as x tends to zero. I think it is an undefined condition and says nothing ...

Comment: Maybe it would be zero at infinity and we haven't an undefined condition there.

Comment: The OP asks about what happens as $x$ approaches negative infinity.

Comment: @Saeed: Are you attempting to answer a different question, about the limit as $x\to+\infty$?

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of it. I solved as x tends to positive values ...

Comment: @Saeed: That limit is $\frac12$, not undefined or zero.

Comment: Now if x tends to negative values then we get a negative infinite there. Rihght?

Comment: @Saeed: Yes, this is mentioned in a bunch of answers here.